# Set selected radio button - NetBeans Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, radio-button

```
if(DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.hasFocus() == true){
    DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.setSelected(hasFocus());
    System.out.print(DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.getComponents().getClass().toString());
}
```

How to improve that code above so that when the radio button is focused it will also be selected? Because I'm using tab to go to next radio button I want is when I tab and focus on radio button it will be selected as well. Given comments and suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Add a `FocusListener` to the button..

Comment: Put 'how to use FocusListener' into your favorite search engine and go from there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i think you are saying this right?i have a focus event for that i am not sure if this is what you are trying to say

Comment: *"whole code"*  No, that's an uncompilable code snippet, not that we really want the 'whole code'.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"i think you are saying.."* Add a `FocusListener` for the button, and use a search engine to find out how to use it.  If you read anything beyond that, it is your own imagination.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.hasFocus() == true){

            DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.setSelected(true);
            DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.requestFocus(true);
            System.out.print(DishFormWeekNoWeek1Rb.getComponents().getClass().toString());
        }
```

@Andrew please give comments on this one it was running ok maybe you can criticize if it has a loop hole